# How to obtain received message from "facebook messages" page using selenium?

Tags: python, html, facebook, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a Python program which will fetch the last message from a person from facebook messages page(similar to facebook messenger) as soon as he texts and print it in a Python IDE.

I am using Selenium to open the page and get to the textbox of the person from whom I am expecting the message.I have no idea how to proceed from there because everytime the new text comes the xpath,selector etc of the new text changes and even if I use expected_conditions, on what should I? The element itself is changing.If I could get the element id or xpath or otherwise, I could easily use gettext() methods to obtain the text.

Below is my minimal code, for reaching upto the textbox of the guy from whom I am expecting messages-

```
from selenium import webdriver 

usr = "x******@gmail.com" 
pwd = "y*****"

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs",{"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications":2}) # Block_notifications
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=opt)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/') 
username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
username_box.send_keys(usr) 
password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass') 
password_box.send_keys(pwd) 
login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_b') 
login_box.click()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/userid") 
textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"""//*[@id="js_i"]/div/div/div""")
```

How to proceed from here, to get the message when he does?

Comment: can you share HTML DOm of element you are trying to access. I cant login into Facebook to see myself.

Comment: Start by xpathing /div/div and grabbing the last data-tooltip-position="left". It corresponds to the last message the other person sent.

Comment: @arundeepchohan can you tell me the code format of data-tooltip-position="left" ?

Comment: It's pretty long but if you //*[@id="js_i"]/div/div/div/div/div . It's a div tag which you can check it's attribute value when searching.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem will be solved by follwing below steps.

1. Switch to frame `driver.switch_to_frame("//iframe[contains(@src,'userid')]")` (Note : Here '**userid**' is chat username.)
2. Use this XPath `//div[@data-hover='tooltip']/div[@role='img']` to identify the facebook smilies or GIF images.
3. Use this XPath `//div[@data-hover='tooltip']/div/span` to read the chat text.

Comment: What is meant by the chat username? Is it the userid of 2nd last line of the code in my question or the nickname or anything else?

Comment: **userid** from 2nd last line of the code in question.

Comment: NoSuchFrameException: Message: //iframe[contains(@src,'id')] error comes up.This was unexpected

Comment: **userid** should be something like : **dilipmeghwal** or it might contain the numbers **1234567765556**. You can find that in browser **url** bar.

Comment: Is there an alternative for choose the last text without changing frames? I am giving the correct userid but it is giving the same error-don't know why.

Comment: Without switching to the frame this is not possible to interact with the element inside a frame. Can you please share element xpath used and the DOM - html.